# How to connect to a heroku rendezvous url from a tcp socket?

Tags: sockets, heroku, tcp, google-chrome-app

I am creating a new on-off dyno with the Heroku Platform API and getting back an url with the format `rendezvous://rendezvous.runtime.heroku.com:5000/{rendezvous-id}`.
Now I want to establish a connection to this url with the chrome.socket.tcp API.

```
chrome.sockets.tcp.create({}, function(createInfo) {
  chrome.sockets.tcp.connect(createInfo.socketId, IP, PORT, onConnectedCallback);
});
```

where `IP` is 'rendezvous.runtime.heroku.com' and `PORT` is 5000, but how could i specify the `rendezvous-id` or do I need to do this?

I found a Ruby implementation of this: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/blob/master/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous.rb

Is it possible to do this in a chrome app?

**Edit**
I read the Ruby implementation. It uses a ssl_socket instance from a OpenSSL library and then just sends the `rendezvous-id`. Can I just use `chrome.socket.tcp.secure` to get an openssl secure socket?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But you will have to implement the rendezvous protocol, whatever it is, yourself on top of raw TCP sockets.

Comment: Or find a JavaScript library that's already implemented it.